# Remove all inline styles but one specific one

Tags: jquery, styles, attr

I have seen posts such as *remove all inline styles* and *remove all classes but one* but I am looking for something else.

Say my element has got an inline style like so:

```
<div id="element" style="display: none; left: 7px; overflow: hidden; height: 159px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: -2px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>
```

How would I go about removing all setted styles, but a specific one?

I can't use `.removeAttr("style")` nor can I use `.attr("style", "")`. What I could do, is get the value that I want, extract it, remove all styles and the add the style again:

```
var el = $("element"),
    elL = el.css("left");

el.removeAttr("style").css("left", elL);
```

But this would cause some flickering. I want a clean, straight solution!

Comment: Add a class with the needed style BEFORE removing the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can override the css style that you want to remove....!! with

$.css();